# Show that every real number between 0 and 1 can be written as the sum of powers of 2

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $(d_n)_n$ be a sequence with the property that $d_n$ can be either $0$ or $1$, and
define a sequence $(a_n)_n$ by

> $a_n=d_1*2^{-1} + d_2*2^{-2} + ... + d_n*2^{-n}, n \in \mathbb{N} $

Then, prove that for every number $a \in [0,1],$ there exists a sequence $(d_n)_n$ such that sequence defined above $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a$.

Solution attempt:

I have shown that $(a_n)_n$ always converges to a number in $[0,1]$ since it is bounded in this interval and it is monotonic.

Then, I have tried to write down $d_n$ for a given $a \in [0,1]$. What I have came up with is the following:

> $d_1= \lfloor 2*a \rfloor, d_{n+1}= \lfloor (a-a_n)*2^n \rfloor$

I believe this works correctly. But since I am using $a_n$ inside $d_n$ and also $d_n$ inside $a_n$, I couldn't go any further with the limit proof. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just use that there is a binary expansion of the real number and every bit $1$ corresponds with a summand which is a power of two (with negative exponent) ?

Comment: @Peter Can I really say that every real number has a binary expansion without proving this question? Isn't that already what I am kind of trying to proof?

Comment: Hm, that is a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine so far, but yes, the problem that you have notice doesn't have an obvious solution.

For an alternative solution: Start with $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$. We shall then define sequences $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ inductively, at each stage guaranteeing that our target number lies in $[a_n,b_n]$.

For this purpose, define $c_{n-1}$ to be the average of $a_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-1}$. Then our target number must be in either $[a_{n-1},c_{n-1}]$ or $[c_{n-1},b_{n-1}]$.
We then define $a_n$ and $b_n$ to be the endpoints of whichever interval it lies in (if it's exactly $c_{n-1}$, then choose the latter, for reasons that will become clear later).

This clearly defines a pair of well-defined sequences. Since they are both monotonic and bounded, they both converge, and $b_n - a_n = 2^{-n}$ for all $n$, so $(b_n - a_n)_n\to 0$, hence they converge to the same value. But also, $(b_n)_n$ is bounded below by our target number, and $(a_n)_n$ is bounded above by our target number, so they must both converge to our target number.

Now, we can reconstruct our sum from these sequences: $d_n$ is zero for each $n$ at which we chose the first interval, and one for each $n$ at which we chose the second (this is why we chose the latter interval two paragraphs up - it means that we get terminating expansions, rather than infinite strings of 1s in our binary expansions).

With that, my $a_n$ is exactly your $a_n$, and we've already shown that it converges as desired.